# How to format numbers with 000 prefix in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery function:

```
if ($("#nuevaFactura").is(':selected')) {
        $("#nuevoDocumentoValorHidden").val('00001');
        $("#nuevoDocumentoValor").val(idDocumento+'-'+'0001');
        $("#idDocumento").val($("#nuevaFactura").val());
      }
```

However, when the value reaches 10, the result I get is '000010', and my target is to get '0010'. And for 100, I would like '00100'. Is there a function in Jquery to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a fixed `4 digit` number with leading zeros, you can do it using the [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method of JQuery like this:

```
/* A fixed pattern of leading zeros */
var pattern = "0000";

/* The real integer number */
var num = 10;

/* Now, get the latest 4 characters of the concatenation string */
/* Example: <pattern + num> will be equal to: 000010 */
/* But latest 4 digits will be: 0010 */
(pattern + num).slice(-4);
```

Check next example:

```js
/* A fixed pattern of leading zeros */
var pattern = "0000";

/* Sample of numbers */
var nums = [1, 10, 56, 100, 715, 1000, 2206];    

/* Now, format the number with leading zeros */
    
nums.forEach(function(num)
{
    console.log((pattern + num).slice(-4));
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. However, the problem comes in when you are getting the values from a database. For example, i just saved Invoice "0001". For getting next invoice displayed in screen, if I use your solution, I will just get "0000002". Do you get me?

Comment: Nope, i don't get you, can you make a better explanation? My solution will never return a string with more than 4 digits.